# How to sum() for three months data including current month

Tags: sql-server-2008, sum, common-table-expression

I have a table in SQL Server that looks something like this

```
ProjectId   BookedHours    FiscalYear  FiscalMonth
--------------------------------------------------
PRJ1        2040            2015-16     1-Apr-15
PRJ1        1816            2015-16     1-May-15
PRJ1        1760            2015-16     1-Jun-15
PRJ1        1832            2015-16     1-Jul-15
PRJ2        1752            2015-16     1-Sep-15
PRJ2        1529            2015-16     1-Oct-15
PRJ2        1336            2015-16     1-Nov-15
PRJ2        1480            2015-16     1-Dec-15
PRJ2        522             2015-16     1-Jan-16
```

I need to sum up the values for current + previous two months booked hours i.e. expected result should look like below table

```
ProjectId   BookedHours    FiscalYear  FiscalMonth  ExpectedValue
-----------------------------------------------------------------
PRJ1        2040            2015-16     1-Apr-15    2040
PRJ1        1816            2015-16     1-May-15    3856
PRJ1        1760            2015-16     1-Jun-15    5616
PRJ1        1832            2015-16     1-Jul-15    5408
PRJ2        1752            2015-16     1-Sep-15    1752
PRJ2        1529            2015-16     1-Oct-15    3281   
PRJ2        1336            2015-16     1-Nov-15    4617
PRJ2        1480            2015-16     1-Dec-15    4345
PRJ2         522            2015-16     1-Jan-16    3338
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach...

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
    row_num = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY FiscalMonth),
    * 
    FROM dbo.Project p
)
SELECT CurrentMonth.ProjectID, CurrentMonth.BookedHours, CurrentMonth.FiscalYear, CurrentMonth.FiscalMonth, 
(CurrentMonth.BookedHours + COALESCE(OneMonthBack.BookedHours, 0) + COALESCE(TwoMonths.BookedHours, 0)) AS ExpectedValue
FROM cte CurrentMonth
LEFT JOIN cte OneMonthBack ON OneMonthBack.row_num = CurrentMonth.row_num - 1
LEFT JOIN cte TwoMonths ON TwoMonths.row_num = CurrentMonth.row_num - 2
```

Hope that works for you.

Comment: Thanks nscheaffer,It worked partially, u can understand from the result table that for different project it has start from row number one again, can you help me please..

below query gives the partial result

Comment: I missed that. You just need to add to each of the LEFT JOIN criteria to set the ProjectIDs equal from each table, but it looks like you already figured that out. Nice work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT *,row_num=ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY Projectid ORDER BY Projectid,FiscalYear,FiscalMonth)
    FROM dbo.Project p
)  

SELECT CM.ProjectID, CM.FiscalYear, CM.FiscalMonth, CM.BookedHours, 
(CM.BookedHours + COALESCE(OMB.BookedHours, 0) + COALESCE(TM.BookedHours, 0)) AS ExpectedValue
FROM cte CM
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte OMB WITH(NOLOCK) ON OMB.row_num = CM.row_num - 1 and CM.Projectid=OMB.Projectid
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte TM WITH(NOLOCK) ON TM.row_num = CM.row_num - 2 and CM.Projectid=TM.Projectid
ORDER BY CM.ProjectID, CM.FiscalYear, CM.FiscMonth ASC
```

Above Query works perfectly for my table